# Wordpress Tiny MCE won't accept line breaks

Tags: tinymce

Encountered an infuriating issue where I f i want to add multiple linebreaks 
 for layout between paragraphs, Wordpress doesn't recognize them in th wysiwig editor. If I enter them in the code window, and publish they DO save, but the next time the Wysiwig is edited and published those breaks disappear.

is there a workaround or a plugin hat lets Tinymce handle this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use TinyMce Advanced. In the TinyMce Advanced settings it gives you to the choice to stop removing the line-breaks. You might give it a try. This is the first plug-in I install after adding a WP Website.

Link:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to ad linebreaks this way.
Every paragraph is divided in `<p>`-tags:

`<p>paragraph 1...</p>`

`<p>paragraph 2...</p>`

You should edit your style.css to ad more space (margin) between the paragraphs.

However, you could add a empty `<p>`-tag like this:

`<p>paragraph 1...</p>`

`<p>&nbsp;</p>`

`<p>paragraph 2...</p>`

Comment: Thanks. I thought I tried that first, but I'll give it another shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a class to the breaks(so in HTML mode obviously) and make sure something follows them, they shouldn't get removed ...

Eg.

```
<br class="a" />
<br class="a" />
Something
```

This method works for me when switching between Visual and HTML, so hope that's of some use to you(though i'll admit it's not *ideal*).